# Smooth scrolling to top of page when you have used margin-top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My content starts with logobox being the first thing:

```
#logobox { width: 178px; height: 204px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 250px; }
```

I am using the script from : http://www.paulund.co.uk/smooth-scroll-to-internal-links-with-jquery

I created a "back to top" button, but it only scrolls back to where the logobox begins, not to the top of the page. Tried creating another  link before logobox, but it won't work.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your [Back to top] button is something like `<a href="#logobox">Top</a>`?

That will always take you to 250px below whatever #logobox is positioned after, in this case the top of the window (again, assuming). In css, margin is an offset - the element #logobox is actually offset 250px so when you jump to it, 250px further down. You can:

1. Switch the #logobox element to use `padding-top: 250px` if that works for your design. instead of `margin-top: 250px`. This actually keeps the top of the box where you're thinking it is right now (vs offsetting it from that position).
2. Drop in a blank element with an id and point your "back to top" button to it. Easily the internet's most popular option, historically. Usually, annoyingly, in the form of `<a name="top"></a>`
3. If #logobox exists inside of an element like `<header id="main-header">` and that element doesn't have a top margin, you can point your [back to top] button there as well (in some cases, that is. The margin top on #logobox will actually affect this depending on the the header's css and other elements in the HTML).

Check out this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/willthemoor/Q7PCm/3/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding an id to the body tag and making your button point to it.